# How to convert int to minutes and seconds?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
event | time_seconds
001   |    67
002   |   150
003   |   145
004   |   831
005   |   453
006   |    78
...
```

the `time_seconds` column is stored as integer but I would like to convert it to MM:SS (minute:seconds) format. Currently it's just seconds, so event 003 is 145 seconds. I'd like to convert it to 02:24.

Here is a reproducible example using `dput`:

```
df <- structure(list(event = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), time_seconds = c(67, 
150, 145, 831, 453, 78)), .Names = c("event", "time_seconds"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use package `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
tm <- seconds_to_period(145)
sprintf("%02d:%02d", minute(tm), second(tm))
```

If convert all column is needed use:

```
library(lubridate)
df$time_seconds <- seconds_to_period(df$time_seconds)
df$time_seconds <- sprintf("%02d:%02d", 
                           minute(df$time_seconds), 
                           second(df$time_seconds))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This has helped a lot, thanks. It's converted it to characters but it seems easy enough to convert to MM:SS.