# Convert number to minutes and seconds

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to convert numbers like 3700 into a minutes and seconds format i.e. 61:40.

I found the following question which is basically what I am after if the time is less than an hour but for my example 3700 it basically will reset to 01:40

[How to convert int to minutes and seconds with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476244/how-to-convert-int-to-minutes-and-seconds-with-r)

Can someone please show me how to modify the code to get to the 61:40 I am after.

Comment: I wont answer since I don't know R but basically all you have to do for the minutes is divide your number by 60 (call the result y = x / 60) and take the integer part of y, for the seconds you need to take the decimal part of y and multiply it by 60 (and round it if you don't care about sub-second time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
as.period(as.period(3700), 'minutes')
[1] "61M 40S"
```

If you need it as `61:40` then use `str_Replace_all`

```
a <- as.period(as.period(3700), 'minutes')
stringr::str_replace_all(a, c(M=":", S = "", " " = ""))
[1] "61:40"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use division along with the modulus operator to manually calculate the number of hours and minutes:

```r
x <- 3700
h <- floor(x / 60)
m <- floor(x %% 60)
paste0(sprintf("%02d", h), ":", sprintf("%02d", m))

[1] "61:40"
```

Note that the calls to `sprintf()` might be needed in case an hour or minute result happens to be less than 10.  In that case, we would expect a leading zero.

Comment: You don’t need `floor()` if you use integer division (`%/%`) instead of regular division. (I also wouldn’t use it when defining `m`: it isn’t necessary for integer values of `x`; and if `x` is fractional then so should `m` be.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use integer division and modulo.

```
> fn <- \(x) {
+   sapply(c(`%/%`, `%%`), \(f) sprintf('%02d', f(x, 60))) |> 
+     paste(collapse=':')
+ }
> fn(3700)
[1] "61:40"
> fn(53)
[1] "00:53"
```